# Using grep to split a line, then search for lines with a number greater than 3

Tags: shell, awk, grep

Let's say I have a file like:

```
thing1(space)thing2(space)thing3(space)thing4
```

E.g.

```
1 apple 3 4
3 banana 3 8
3 pear 11 12
13 cheeto 15 16
```

Can I only show lines where `thing3` is greater than 3? (i.e. pear and cheeto)

I can easily do this in python, but can we do this in the shell? Maybe with awk? I'm still researching this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that easily with `awk` if that is an option available to you by saying:

```
awk '$3>3' inputFile
```

```
$ cat file
1 apple 3 4
3 banana 3 8
3 pear 11 12
13 cheeto 15 16
```

```
$ awk '$3>3' file
3 pear 11 12
13 cheeto 15 16
```

`awk` by default splits the line in to fields delimited by space and assigns them to variable which can be referenced by stating the column number. In your case you need to reference it by `$3`.

Comment: Thanks this works! Bizarrely, using double quotes here e.g. "$3>3" produces a syntax error on my redhat system. Only single quotes work. Just FYI if anyone else gets this problem :)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables You're welcome. The single quotes around `awk` prevents `shell` from interpreting any `awk` characters as special `shell` characters.